# How to load attach css to content loaded by Request class

Tags: javascript, mootools, javascript-framework

I am using mootools v1.3 for my application. i have implemented two asychronous calls to myCSS.php and myContent.php. First its loading CSS and attaching it at the top in < body > tag
inside a < script > tag. then the content is loaded at the bottom of < body > tag.

The asynchronous calls are :

```
var myRequest =  new Request({  async: false,  method: 'post',  
onSuccess: function(html) { /* Code to attach html value in <body> tag */ },
});
myRequest.send({url: myCSS.php});
myRequest.send({url: myContent.php});
```

In the CSS there is a class

```
.content_disp {
padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #333; }
```

And in myContent.php :

```
<div class="content_disp"> some data...... </div>
```

the problem is the  is not displayed with the properties of CSS class .content_disp
I cant figure out where its getting wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at how the Asset class from Mootools More does this. The css is first applied to a link element, which is then injected into the document head.  It's not clear from your sample, what element you're inserting the raw css source into.

```
css: function(source, properties){
    properties = properties || {};
    var onload = properties.onload || properties.onLoad;
    if (onload){
        properties.events = properties.events || {};
        properties.events.load = onload;
        delete properties.onload;
        delete properties.onLoad;
    }
    return new Element('link', Object.merge({
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        media: 'screen',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: source
    }, properties)).inject(document.head);
},
```

Comment: function(html) {
document.body.innerHTML = '<script type="text/css"> ' + html + ' </script><div id="data_loader"></div>' + document.body.innerHTML;
} : this is the code that handles the onSuccess event for Request object.

Comment: thanks...!! i got the solution. It was the code that handles onSuccess event of myRequest. i changed "document.body.innerHTML" to "document.head.innerHTML".

Answer (score 0):

The Updated working code is :

```
var myRequest =  new Request({  async: false,  method: 'post',  
onSuccess: function(html) { 
 document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + 
 '<style type="text/css"> ' + html + ' </style><div id="data_loader"></div>';
} });
myRequest.send({url: 'myCSS.php'});
myRequest.send({url: 'myContent.php'});
```

Thanks [leeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408106/leeeb) 
  :)